AzureOpenAI returning openai.NotFoundError
I am trying to create embeddings as described here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/ai-services/openai/how-to/embeddings.md
So this:
import os
from openai import AzureOpenAI

client = AzureOpenAI(
  api_key = os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY"),  
  api_version = "2023-05-15",
  azure_endpoint =os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT") 
)

response = client.embeddings.create(
    input = "Your text string goes here",
    model= "text-embedding-ada-002"
)

print(response.model_dump_json(indent=2))

I get the error openai.NotFoundError: Error code: 404 - {'error': {'code': 'DeploymentNotFound', 'message': 'The API deployment for this resource does not exist. If you created the deployment within the last 5 minutes, please wait a moment and try again.'}}
I am using openai version 1.14.3. I copied the code exactly from the link, the environment variables are set up correctly and this worked fine with langchain_openai.AzureChatOpenAI. The deployment is set up in the environment variable AZURE_OPENAI_API_DEPLOYMENT_NAME.

In the code sample you provided, the deployment name (= the name of the model that you deployed) is not used in the call. You mentioned that it is set in a variable called AZURE_OPENAI_API_DEPLOYMENT_NAME, but you should use it.
Replace:
response = client.embeddings.create(
    input = "Your text string goes here",
    model= "text-embedding-ada-002"
)

by:
response = client.embeddings.create(
    input = "Your text string goes here",
    model= os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_API_DEPLOYMENT_NAME")
)


My deployment name doesn't correspond to an embedding model, that is a different issue.

Do you have deployed an embedding model?

No, I don't understand what you mean. How would I do that? That is not supposed to be necessary for it to work. Like I said, I followed the example on the linked page exactly, I only changed the version name to the one I am using, which works with AzureChatOpenAI

You are using code that should create embeddings of a text. So you must first deploy a model used for embeddings, for exemple text-ada-embedding-002, in your Azure OpenAI resource. The sample cannot run without providing an Azure OpenAI resource with the appropriate models deployed in it
